# HTML text input triggers change event too late

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a problem with my input, where it calls my change event, only after i click away from the input. I want the event to be called when the user adds some text to my input.

```js
function textChange(ele) {
    let btn = document.getElementById("addThingBtn");
    if (ele.value.length) btn.disabled = false;
    else btn.disabled = true;
}
```

```css
input {
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="newThingName" onchange="textChange(this);" placeholder="new thing name">
<button id="addThingBtn" onclick="addThing();" disabled> Add thing </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually looking for the [input event,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) not for the change event.

```js
function textChange(ele) {
    let btn = document.getElementById("addThingBtn");
    if (ele.value.length) btn.disabled = false;
    else btn.disabled = true;
}
```

```css
input {
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="newThingName" oninput="textChange(this);" placeholder="new thing name">
<button id="addThingBtn" onclick="addThing();" disabled> Add thing </button>
```